# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.getPages()

Tags: java, ruby, jar, jruby, pdfbox

When I use Jruby and pdfbox, I encounter a problem and a stack trace is thrown.

The jar includes this method.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.getPages()Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPageTree;
        at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java:266)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.getText(org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.java:227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:497)
        at RUBY.perform(D:/workspace/PDF/pdf_extractor/tabula/lib/tabula_job_executor/jobs/generate_speculate_loc.rb:53)
        at org.jruby.RubyFixnum.times(org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java:280)
        at RUBY.perform(D:/workspace/PDF/pdf_extractor/tabula/lib/tabula_job_executor/jobs/generate_speculate_loc.rb:49)
        at RUBY.call(D:/workspace/PDF/pdf_extractor/tabula/lib/tabula_job_executor/executor.rb:104)
        at GenerateSpeculateLocJob_1159411179.call(GenerateSpeculateLocJob_1159411179.gen:13)
        at GenerateSpeculateLocJob_1159411179.call(GenerateSpeculateLocJob_1159411179.gen:13)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: Most likely you either use different versions of iText at compile time and run time or you have multiple versions of PDFBox in your class path at run time and the wrong `PDDocument` class version is loaded.

Comment: Thank you,I change the version of jar and solve this problem.

Comment: If the problem has been solved, please either delete the question, or answer it yourself.

Comment: I used the Tabula, which came with pdfbox, but I didn't find out before and imported the new pdfbox, so there was a version conflict

Comment: I had a problem similar to yours using Eclipse + Tomcat in a java project. I noticed that old libs were contaminating the container. I solved it by manually removing the old libs, in the directory C:\TOMCAT\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\wtpwebapps\mp-diariooficial\WEB-INF\lib